# matching regex string with quotations and href

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to use regex to match the

```
  <a href = "something" >
```

in the string below,
 but None is printed.

```
E = '<a> test <a href> <a href = "something" ><a href="anything">'
H = re.match('^[<a href = ]\".\" >$' , E)
print (H)
```

Comment: Don't use regex for parsing html!

Comment: and what are you trying to match?

Comment: i am not parsing HTML , its just an exercise to practice , I am only trying to search in the string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend that you don't use regex to parse HTML (for that there is [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/))
Since you've said that you aren't, Here's something:

```
>>> regex = re.compile("(<\s*a\s*href\s*=\s*\"something\"\s*>)+")
# Run findall
>>> regex.findall(string)
[u'<a href = "something" >'] # your tag
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't parse html with regex.

Here's an example using BeautifulSoup:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer


html_string = '<a> test <a href> <a href = "something" ><a href="anything">'
for link in BeautifulSoup(html_string, parseOnlyThese=SoupStrainer('a')):
    print link.get('href')
```